# How do I configure this jquery and javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is that when I go to click "remove", it removes all of the items instead of just one. I feel I need to use an array to fix the problem but I just don't know how I'd go about doing that.

I also would like to add the ability to list large amounts in the "Amount" box so my staff members don't have to keep clicking "Shirt" for large orders. For example, when the amount of 30 is typed in to "Amount", and "Add" is clicked, I'd like it to list "Ticket(x30)" instead of my staff having to click "Add" 30 times.

Currently, when I click "remove", I only mean to remove one item, but I'm guessing because the items I'm removing are text-values and not arrays, it's difficult to specify that I want to remove only 1 item.

Also, with the custom "amount", I just can't get that right to save my life. I don't even know where to start. Everything I tried has failed.

The fiddle is attached:
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xb8hLmsr/)

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    ticket = 1;
    //setting action for num-buttonTicket when clicked
    $(".num-buttonTicket").click(function(){
        $(".num-buttonTicket").css({background: "#ff6a00"});
        $(".num-buttonVIP").css({background: ""});
        $(".num-buttonShirt").css({background: ""});
        $(".remove-button").css({background: ""});
        $(".add-button").css({background: ""});
        ticket = 3;
    });
    //setting action for num-buttonVIP when clicked
    $(".num-buttonVIP").click(function() {
        $(".num-buttonVIP").css({background: "#ff6a00"});
        $(".num-buttonTicket").css({background: ""});
        $(".num-buttonShirt").css({background: ""});
        $(".remove-button").css({background: ""});
        $(".add-button").css({background: ""});
        ticket = 4;
    });
    //setting action for num-buttonShirt when clicked
    $(".num-buttonShirt").click(function() {
        $(".num-buttonShirt").css({background: "#ff6a00"});
        $(".num-buttonTicket").css({background: ""});
        $(".num-buttonVIP").css({background: ""});
        $(".remove-button").css({background: ""});
        $(".add-button").css({background: ""});
        ticket = 5;
    });
    $(".clear-button").click(function() {
        var result = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Clear This Transaction?");
if (result==true) {
    $(".num-buttonShirt").css({background: ""});
        $(".num-buttonTicket").css({background: ""});
        $(".num-buttonVIP").css({background: ""});
        $(".remove-button").css({background: ""});
        $(".add-button").css({background: ""});
        ticket = 1
        document.frm.display.value = "";
}
    });

    //setting conditions for add-button when clicked
    $(".add-button").click(function() {
        //set the if
        if (ticket > 2) {
            $(".add-button").css({background: "#ff6a00"});
            $(".remove-button").css({background: ""});
        }
        else {
            alert("First, select an item you would like to add.");
        }
        //////////////Code for posting Top Values
        if (ticket == 3){document.frm.display.value += " + Ticket"
            };

        if (ticket == 4){document.frm.display.value += " + VIP"
            };

        if (ticket == 5){document.frm.display.value += " + Shirt"
            };
        //////////////end
    });

    $(".remove-button").click(function() {
        //set the if
        if (ticket > 2) {
            $(".remove-button").css({background: "#ff6a00"});
            $(".add-button").css({background: ""});
        }
        else {
            alert("First, select an item you would like to remove.");
        }
        //////////////Code for posting Top Values

        if (ticket == 3){document.frm.display.value -= " + Ticket"
            };

        if (ticket == 4){document.frm.display.value -= " + VIP"
            };

        if (ticket == 5){document.frm.display.value -= " + Shirt"
            };
        //////////////end
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="store"><!--start of store-->
<div id="side"><!--start of side-->
<div id="sidepanel"> <!--start of sidepanel-->
    <div id="sidepaneltitle"><!--start of sidepaneltitle-->
    STORE
    </div><!--end of sidepaneltitle-->

    <div class="num-buttonTicket">TICKET</div>
    </br>
    <div class="num-buttonVIP">VIP TICKET</div>
    </br>
    <div class="num-buttonShirt">SHIRT</div>
    </br>

    <div id="spacer"><!--start of spacer-->
    <div class="add-button">ADD</div>
    <div class="remove-button">REMOVE</div>
    <div class="clear-button">CLEAR</div>
    <div class="submit-button">NEW</div>
    <div class="final-button">FINAL</div>
    </div><!--end of spacer-->

</div><!--end of sidepabel-->
</div><!--end of side-->
<div id="calculatorPROP"><!--start of calculatorPROP-->
<div id="calculator"><!--start of calculator-->
<form name="frm">
<input type="text" id="display" value=""readonly /> 
<div id="blank"><!--start of blank-->
<input type="text" id="display2" value=""/> 
</form>
</div><!--end of blank-->
</div><!--end of calculator-->
</div><!--end of calculatorPROP-->
<form name="amount">
<input type="text" id="amount" value="" placeholder="amount"/>
</form>
</div><!--end of store-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the add, remove, and clear functions to make them utilize arrays instead of direct DOM manipulation to store the order.

- Removing items now works properly, and the item you are deleting doesn't have to be the last item in the list (as the pseudo-ish code you had written *would have* done). See next item for more about adding and removing.
- You can now add one or more of the same item in one click by changing the value of the quantity field next to the "ADD" button, or remove a number of the selected item by changing the value of the quantity field next to the "REMOVE" button.
- You can also increase these quantities quickly by scrolling inside the quantity field (this is a built-in functionality of the "number" input type)
- jQuery has a function `[array].join(string);` which allows your list of items at the top to only contain " + " in between items after the first one (no more "+ Shirt + Shirt").
- I also made a few formatting and CSS changes, just to make things fit better. If you want the border radius and title back, see the second link at the bottom for an older version without those modifications (also lacks some scripting modifications).

Code Samples:

```
//Add Function    
if (ticket > 2){
        for (i = 0; i < (Number($("#amountadd").val())||1); i++) { 
        order.push(items[ticket-3]);
        }
        //-3 is because the array (at the top of the code) has keys 0,1,2 and the items have numbers 3,4,5.
    };
document.frm.display.value = order.join(" + ");

//Remove Function
    for (i = 0; i < (Number($("#amountrem").val())||1); i++) {
        if (order.indexOf(items[ticket-3]) > -1) {
            order.splice(order.lastIndexOf(items[ticket-3]),1);
        }
    }
    document.frm.display.value = order.join(" + ");
```

Final version: https://jsfiddle.net/xb8hLmsr/5/
Version with border radius and title (also lacks some scripting modifications; if you use this, I recommend copying in the JavaScript from the first link): https://jsfiddle.net/xb8hLmsr/2/

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: @Crash54Fox If this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking on the check mark in the top left corner.